# How to prevent to load a javascript and css file on iOS and Android devices?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, user-agent

How to prevent to load a js file on iOS and Android devices? I'm making a website for all devices. I want to add some specific JavaScript+CSS effect only for desktop user not to iPhone,iPad and Android, Windows phone users. So can i stop to load some specific JavaScript and CSS files to load on specific devices.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Yepnope](http://yepnopejs.com/) library to conditionally load javascript files. http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/ has libraries to detect if the website is loaded onto a mobile. Therefore you can combine both.

Comment: Upvote: as the asker wants to selectively load resources, CSS media queries alone are not sufficient. As usual, detecting specific devices via user-agent strings should be avoided where it's otherwise possible to rely on feature detection libraries like Modernizr.

Answer (score 0):

You can try detecting the useragent and then dynamically loading the scripts/css you want.

Answer (score 0):

For css you should really try mediaqueries. For example, if you want to set css only for iPhone you can use:

```
/* Portrait */
@media screen and (max-width: 320px) {
    body { opacity: 1; }
}
/* Landscape */
@media screen and (min-width: 321px) and (max-width: 480px) {
    body { opacity: 0; }
}
```

But for desktop it's the same, you select what is your min-widh and max-width.

For Js, I advise you to read this: http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2010/08/combining_media.html

Comment: I'm already using media queries. my question to load css and js files.

Comment: Maybe you can try 

`if (screen.width < 600) {
 // don’t download complicated script
 // use low-source images instead of full-source ones
}`
You should read **JavaScript pairing** by following the url i've just gave you.

Comment: iPad in landscape mode and many desktop monitor has same resolution 1024x768

Comment: The only ressources i've found right now show me there are not "good" solutions. I've just found a good article about this, I think you should read: http://www.hand-interactive.com/resources/detect-mobile-javascript.htm Alternatively, you could see if the Yepnope library fits for your needs or not

Answer (score 0):

Call your CSS files using media queries from within your JavaScript file.